# how to set alert box ok button in alertify.alert('');

Tags: javascript

```
alertify.alert("Welcome..");
window.location.href="index.php";
```

this is my code for alert but there without click on ok button page goes to index.php how to fix it??

Comment: The question is way too broad, so the answer will be the same: you have to set up a click handler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`alertify.alert` does not block the execution of the code like `alert`  does.

You have to use a callback:

```
alertify.alert("Welcome..", function() {
  window.location.href="index.php";
});
```